# SSIS DB migration

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, database-migration, sql-server-2017

How to migrate SSISDB from 2012 to 2017?

I have tried using dba tools but it failed as the ssis assembley is missing. How every it is pointing to the wrong version sql 2019.

Will backup/restore works for 2012 to 2017 migration

Comment: There is not enough detail in your question for anyone to provide you with an answer. And Stack Overflow is about programming questions. This is a database administration question. While you are obviously in a bad spot, the question as presented should be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it both lacks detail and clarity, and is on the wrong site.

Comment: You will probably get a better answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/